# How to cache in Web Matrix style C# Razor project NO MVC, NO WEBFORMS

Tags: caching, matrix

Is there a server-side way to cache at page level in Razor c# in a matrix-style project. This is having NO MVC and no Web forms. Please only answer for plain on cshtml pages being directly interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for pure Matrix style, use the HelperResponse like so:

```
@{
 // check if in cache, if not get direct then set cache
 HelperResponse helperResponse = Cache["myhelper"] as HelperResponse;
 if (helperResponse == null) {
    helperResponse = myhelper();
    Cache["myhelper"] = helperResponse;
 }
 // output on page
 @helperResponse

}
```

Answer (score 0):

set caching at the IIS level for the file extensions you want to cache.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`OutputCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.responseextensions.outputcache%28v=vs.99%29.aspx), which is available as an extension method available on the [`Response`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.response%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) object.